# Is it a good idea to use the same netty EventLoopGroup for both ServerBootstrap and Bootstrap?

Tags: netty, nio, event-loop

There is a small [Netty Best Practice Guide](http://normanmaurer.me/presentations/2014-facebook-eng-netty/slides.html#25.0) by Norman Maurer that suggests to re-use a NioEventLoopGroup whenever possible, more precisely, the guide states

> Re-use EventLoopGroup if you can!

In my case, I wrote an application that multiplexes financial tick data to a bunch of connected web socket clients. There are currently three bootstraps in place, currently all of them use a separate NioEventLoopGroup:

- 1 x ServerBootStrap handling the connected web sockets.
- 1 x Bootstrap attached to the ServerBootStrap.
- 2 x Bootstrap for different tick data sources (remote servers).

Reading this particular slide, I'd simply create my NioEventLoopGroup once and use it for all listed BootStraps.

The problem is, I don't know if this is a good idea nor if there is any restriction. The quote sates "re-use ... if you can!" but I don't know the limitations this statement implies.

To state some numbers: The ServerBootStrap should handle ~10k connected web socket clients. The data sources will remain the same, thus 2 keep-alive connections to a remote server.

Happy about any comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this is totally fine. As long as you don't do any blocking operations in any place. Using the same `EventLoopGroup` may save you some memory, maybe some CPU. It really depends on your use cases.

However, in your case, I would prefer to go with 2 `EventLoopGroup`. 1 for ServerBootstrap, 1 for Bootstrap. This is because with high load (and 10k web sockets seems to like possible high load) it would be easier for you to detect bottlenecks. At least you'll be sure that the problem is not from Bootstrap connections.

I'm saying this as recently I had to split my single `EventLoopGroup` to two exactly in the same situation in order to find cause of the high CPU usage.

Comment: If I understand you correclty, you'd use the same EventLoopGroup for the servers boss and worker group: 
`EventLoopGroup serverEventLoop = new NioEventLoopGroup();
ServerBootstrap server = new ServerBootstrap();
server.group(serverEventLoop, serverEventLoop)` and a separate one for my tick source bootstraps: 
`EventLoopGroup tickEventLoop = new NioEventLoopGroup();
Bootstrap source = new Bootstrap();
source.group(tickEventLoop);`

Comment: No. Boss and workers are always separate groups - https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/blob/master/server/core/src/main/java/cc/blynk/server/transport/TransportTypeHolder.java#L24 and usage - https://github.com/blynkkk/blynk-server/blob/master/server/core/src/main/java/cc/blynk/server/core/BaseServer.java#L25